# Convert to absolute value in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

How do I convert a negative number to an absolute value in Objective-C?

i.e.

-10

becomes

10?

Comment: @SalvadorDali: There is nothing wrong with SO; the question didn't take effort and doesn't follow the SO guidelines, while the answer is in-depth and correct.

Answer (score 462, accepted):

Depending on the type of your variable, one of `abs(int)`, `labs(long)`, `llabs(long long)`, `imaxabs(intmax_t)`, `fabsf(float)`, `fabs(double)`, or `fabsl(long double)`.

Those functions are all part of the C standard library, and so are present both in Objective-C and plain C (and are generally available in C++ programs too.)

(Alas, there is no `habs(short)` function. Or `scabs(signed char)` for that matter...)

---

Apple's and GNU's Objective-C headers also include an `ABS()` macro which is type-agnostic. I don't recommend using `ABS()` however as it is not guaranteed to be side-effect-safe. For instance, `ABS(a++)` will have an undefined result.

---

If you're using C++ or Objective-C++, you can bring in the `<cmath>` header and use `std::abs()`, which is templated for all the standard integer and floating-point types.

Comment: Or you could use the ABS macro, which works on any number type.

Comment: @ugsomethingsomething `ABS()` isn't side-effect safe on all compilers, though, which is why I don't recommend using it.

Comment: It is actually: fabsf(double) fabs(float)

Comment: @Alex no, these are the definitions in math.h: `extern float fabsf(float);
extern double fabs(double);`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function to get the absolute value:

```
+(NSNumber *)absoluteValue:(NSNumber *)input {
  return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:fabs([input doubleValue])];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are curious as to what they are doing in the abs() function:

```
char abs(char i) {
    return -(i & 128) ^ i;
}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31360535)