# Absolute value of NSInteger

Tags: objective-c

Referring to [Convert to absolute value in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717060/convert-to-absolute-value-in-objective-c) I'm wondering if there are functions for NS typedefed types. Or is `abs(NSInteger)` okay? Is it architecture-safe?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use ABS() macro, which is defined in NSObjCRuntime.h, it is architecture-safe.

Comment: Won for NSObjCRuntime.h hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

You can use Foundation’s ABS() macro:

```
NSInteger a = 5;
NSInteger b = -5;
NSLog(@"%ld %ld", ABS(a), ABS(b));
```

Comment: +1 I've been using `MAX` and `MIN` for years and never seen `ABS`. Good to know.

Comment: I never knew that: +1.  Anyway, the `abs()` *function* from the C library is not OK since its parameter is a C `int` which is usually 32 bits in the OS X dev environment whereas NSInteger is the same width as the architecture i.e. 32 or 64 bits.

Answer (score 3):

While the two posted answers are absolutely correct about using the `ABS()` macro, it should certainly be noted that `NSIntegerMin`, whose true absolute value can not be represented as an `NSInteger` returns itself when the `ABS()` function is called.

Presuming a 64-bit system:

```
NSLog(@"ld", ABS(NSIntegerMin)); 
// prints: -9223372036854775808

NSLog(@"%ld", ABS(NSIntegerMin + 1)); 
// prints: 9223372036854775807, which == NSIntegerMax
```

The same results will happen on a 32-bit system, but the numbers will be +2147483647 and -2147483648