# What's the equivalent of Math.abs() in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert to absolute value in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717060/convert-to-absolute-value-in-objective-c)

As i am playing with 2d graphics, i'd like to calculate amount of points object has moved between 2 `CGPoints`. Given that object can move in both direction, i am only interested in sheer number of points representing the difference.

In `Java` i'd `Math.abs(startpoint.x - endpoint.x)`

How can i do the same in `Objective-C`?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There are C functions from `<math.h>` that will do what you want:

```
abs(int val);
labs(long val);
llabs(long long val);
fabs(double val);
fabsf(float val);
fabsl(long double val):
```

Given that `CGPoint` structures are composed of `CGFloat`s, you should use `fabsf` here.

Check out the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_mathematical_functions)

Comment: I know that it was written long time ago, but your advice is not correct, since CGFloat is double you should use `fabs`

Comment: What about `ABS`? It seems to be a more convenient way.