# If Statement conditioning

Tags: xcode, if-statement

ok, this is a bit of a crazy ask, but I have been banging my head all day and there must be an easier way of doing this!

I have 2 values and I want to test these values against each other but there could be a + or - 10 difference between them that is acceptable.

All I keep thinking is that I will have to write a huge statement with lots of OR's in there i.e

```
if (red = red1) || (red == red1 + 1) || (red == red1 + 2) etc.....
```

Please someone put me out of my misery and tell me there is an easier way!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: Assuming these are integer values:

```
if (abs(red - red1) <= 10) {
}
```

If instead you have float values:

```
if (fabs(red - red1) <= 10.0) {
}
```

There are several other absolute value functions available depending on the type of values. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4717090/830760) for more info

Comment: Judging from his attempt with `.. red == red1 + 1 ..` they're integers.

Comment: @aioobe - I agree, which is why I up voted your answer. But it also seemed possible that this was asked by an inexperienced developer who might possibly try to use "red + 1" even if red weren't an integer.

Comment: Hi, it was an integer that I was passing :)

Answer (score 3):

Check if the absolute value of the difference between the two numbers is less than 10.

```
if (abs(red - red1) <= 10)
    ...
```