# Inverting a negative NSNumber

Tags: ios, nsnumber

Can anyone tell me the most efficient way to make a negative NSNumber positive?

Comment: NSNumber itself is not a number, you can use `ABS` to get the absolute value of any of its number representations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question : 

   [Convert to absolute value in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717060/convert-to-absolute-value-in-objective-c)

Comment: @EmilieLessard This is not a duplicate, though the other question certainly explains how to do parts of this one.

Comment: Do you know where did the `NSNumber` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the absolute value like that:

```
number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:fabs([number doubleValue])];
```

Comment: Got this  : Incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'NSNumber *' to parameter of type 'int'

Comment: Except you might have a decimal value there.

Answer (score 3):

Doing this generically is surprisingly complex, because you need to find out the proper type of the number inside `NSNumber`.

Here is one way of doing it: add a category, and use a `switch` statement in the implementation to dispatch on the value of `objCType`

```
@interface NSNumber (AbsoluteValue)

-(NSNumber*)abs;

@end

@implementation NSNumber (AbsoluteValue)

-(NSNumber*)abs {
    switch (self.objCType[0]) {
        // Cases below cover only signed types
      case 'c': return [NSNumber numberWithChar:abs([self charValue])];
      case 's': return [NSNumber numberWithShort:abs([self shortValue])];
      case 'i': return [NSNumber numberWithInt:abs([self intValue])];
      case 'q': return [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:llabs([self longLongValue])];
      case 'f': return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fabsf([self floatValue])];
      case 'd': return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:fabs([self doubleValue])];
      // Otherwise, the number is of an unsigned type, so it can be returned directly
      default: return self;
    }
}

@end
```

You can optimize this by returning `self` when the number is positive.

Comment: Except you should never rely on `NSNumber` `objCType`.

Comment: @A-Live I am very curious as to the origins of such a categorical judgement. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Because of [Note that number objects do not necessarily preserve the type they are created with.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html), e.g. `BOOL` value might be saved as `char`.

Comment: @A-Live How is it relevant to the task at hand, i.e. obtaining the absolute value of a number?

Comment: Absolute value of a bool ?

Comment: @A-Live The bool itself?

Comment: That is the only one I know that is converted internally. I can't guarantee there's no and won't be more, can you ?

Comment: @A-Live That's the thing, I don't need such a guarantee to make a method that is guaranteed to work. There is no requirement to convert to the exact type with which `NSNumber` has been created, because that type cannot be retrieved in any event. My code guarantees that the value is going to fit into whatever type that `NSNumber` has decided that it's going to fit, so it is guaranteed to work. The only change that is going to break this is an addition of a completely different type to `NSNumber`, say, `NSDecimal`. But that would be a different story altogether.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, thanks for the explanation.