# iOS, find absolute value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a label that updates accelerometer readings every 1.0 seconds. I don't want the number to go below 0 when it is updating which happens frequently with the accelerometer.

How do I find the absolute value of a number in a label using objective-c?

Here is the code...

```
 currentAccel = (accel);
```

Accel is a float and also what I need to determine the absolute value of.

Comment: currentAccel = (accel - 1);

Comment: NSString *currentAccellString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%@",currentAccel, @"" ];
    currentg.text = currentAccellString;

Comment: Like I want it to start at 0 ( which is why i have accel - 1) but I don't want it to go below 0\

Comment: Why dont you just use a simple if statement like if(yourNumber>=0)yourLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%f",yourNumber];?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean you could use one of the many methods described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4717090/3613537) For example `fabs(accelOutput);` or something similar depending on your input type.

I'm just curious why you'd want to do this, the number is negative for a reason.